# Is it possible to create an application that hides the notifications and the content of calls and messages?

Tags: android

Is possible to create an application that hides the notifications and the content of calls and messages? and store them somewhere else to only be accessed later

for android 2.2 and newer? (and what about android 2.1?)

Comment: What do you mean by 'content of calls' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. With "messages", I suppose you're referring to text messages. Users can choose any app to store their text messages, so if you're using a 3rd party app, it may store the text messages in its own private database. So you neither will be able to access (and block) this database, you also won't be able to tell this 3rd party app what to do.

Some phones even ship with custom text message apps that were written by the phone manufacturer.

What you're asking for is presumably only possible on a phone that you have full control over, i.e. you decide what apps there are on it.

Comment: So if "myMessageApp" is defined to store my text messages, then I can make this app to automatically filter the messages that will be shown, as I have total control over the application I make? So if I receive a message is automatically hidden and no notification is shown;

Comment: If you write a text message app, then you can do anything with it you want. If you user decides to install another text message app instead, then you have no control over it.